# unity generate project.pbxproj in plist file format insted of old ASCII file format

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, unity-game-engine

When I integrated new facebook SDK 3.1.2 for unity, the `project.pbxproj` file generate in plist format. This is causing parsing issue when FB SDK try to change it.

Comment: Do you get the same problem with the facebook SDK 4.2.1 version?

Comment: 3.1.2 is the latest version for unity IOS. The sample project from facebook running fine....

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is modify the project in Xcode (change the name of a folder and then change it back) and Xcode will re-save the project back to the common format. This is a slight pain the butt, and I haven't found a way to automate this.